# ratiotest and radius of convergence of Taylor expansion of $x\sin(x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Today I helped a student who did not understand Taylor approximations. One of the exercises he had trouble with, was to determine the Taylor series of the function $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x\sin(x)$$
around $0$.

The Taylor-approximation only has even powers of $x$. The solution he had, determined the radius of convergence using the ratio test. However, the ratio test uses consecutive coefficients $c_k$ (if the power series is $\sum c_k(x-a)^k$ and all $c_{2k+1}$ are zero. In the solution, the ratio of $c_{2k}/c_{2k+2}$ is computed and its limit is taken.

My question: is there a theorem which states that we can 'skip' coefficients because they are zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the root test.
Here the best thing is to note that the whole series can be written as a power series in $x^2$, and using the ratio test on this new power series yields the result for the new power series, thus for the original one.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: suppose that the radius of convergence would turn out to be finite using the root-test and after rewritting as powers of $x^2$, do I have to take this into account (i.e. does the radius of convergence needs to be squared or something in that case?)

Comment: Yes: if the radius of $\sum_n{a_nx^n}$ is $R \geq 0$, the radius of $\sum_n{a_nx^{2n}}$ is $R^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!..